# Infusionsoft Get Emails that were sent to all Contacts of a specific Tag

Tags: php, infusionsoft

I am trying to get all emails that were sent to all contacts of a specific Tag.

I was checking [Graphly](https://app.graphly.io/) and I noticed that they have this reporting called "Daily & Hourly Email Engagement" and they were able to group by an email to a specific Tag.

Here is their feature of that function:
[image]

I am aware that Infusionsoft has an [API for Email](https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/rest/#!/Email/listEmailsUsingGET). But their API does not support grouping of emails by tags. They only have parameters of `contact_id` and `email`.

How did Graphly did their's? Am I missing something here?

I have been wondering for the past 3 days already. Your help is a gold mine to me!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose they may combine results of several API requests. For example, it's possible to [load contacts by a tag](https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/rest/#!/Tags/listContactsForTagIdUsingGET) and use contact id in [list emails](https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/rest/#!/Email/listEmailsUsingGET) request.

There's also some chance a [legacy API](https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/table-schema/) data is in use.